# Can i use case in a OLE DB Command in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have lookup and then it goes into a OLE DB Command.
I wounder if this is possible.
This is not the right one but just an example.

It doesn't give error but i
wonder if it does what I want in the order or if the criteria don't get met it skip that,
And it goes of sync?

Update tabel

set CurretYear = CASE WHEN Year = '2022' THEN ? END

, status = ?

WHERE PErsonID = ?

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question correctly. In order for your command to be completed, you must add an else to case. like this : `set CurretYear = CASE WHEN Year = '2022' THEN ? ELSE CurretYear END`

Comment: It sould do nothing if the criteria is not met. So the should be nore else